# pass a input to a json to open the right json file

Tags: python

Instead of

```
if self.x == '111' and self.y == '':
    with open('111.json', 'r') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)

else self.x == '149' and self.y == '':
    with open('149.json', 'r') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
```

How do i do something like this?

```
#input get from user
input = 149
if self.y == '':
    with open('input.json', 'r') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
```

I am trying to get the input to determine which file to read, i try some ways like `(input).json` or `(self.y).json` but it show me "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'".

Any help please.

Comment: `f'{input}.json`? Or just `str(input) + '.json'`?

Comment: thanks that give me an idea and i got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#:%7E:text=f-Strings%3A%20A%20New%20and%20Improved%20Way%20to%20Format,You%20are%20a%20comedian.%20...%204%20Speed.%20)

```py
x = input("Enter : ")
if self.y == '':
    with open(f'{x}.json', 'r') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
```